# Why do I get "irrelevant" URLs in the full referrer field in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, analytics, web-traffic

[image: Google Analytics settings used in this question]When looking in Google Analytics for referrers to a specific page, I use the following:

1. Navigate to Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages
2. Search and select the page that I need.
3. Secondary dimension > Behaviour > Full Referrer

In the results, I get certain URLs which refer to specific pages that do not have links to the page I have chosen (what I am calling "irrelevant", there would be a better term for this).  The URLs are usually content from other sites that do refer traffic to my site, but not links specifically from the page listed in the **Full Referrer** results (i.e. that site does link to another page on my site).

For example, one of the URLs is from click tracking from my EDM system for an email sent before this page existed, so it's not possible for it to have a link to this new page on it, but the EDM system has got links to the page in later emails.

Does this problem mean that the results are unreliable, or is there an additional interpretation that I need to apply to the results.  For example, should I interpret that the visitor went to my site from that referral URL and then subsequently navigated to the specific page?

Another referral report I use for the same purpose is to select in **Step 3** (above) Secondary dimension > Aquisition > Source/Medium which gives the domain of the referral site rather than the full URL.

Comment: Can you give us some screen-shot examples?? Otherwise, we have no idea of what you are seeing and how it applies. Sorry. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi closetnoc!  Yes I will do that now!

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: Oh. I am sorry. I was hoping to see some example referrers. For the record, I do not know GA much at all, however, we have seen some funny spam stuff and I thought adding the problem URLs would help our experienced users determine what is happening. It is likely that someone here will have a clue.

Comment: OK, I see, no the URLs are not from problem sites.  They are all known and regular sites from networks that I am familiar with, some that I manage myself.  I wouldn't need a screenshot to share the URLs, and because they are part of my network I've chosen not to share them.

Comment: Okay. Let's see what some of our users can figure out. GA questions are probably the number one question asked here so there are plenty of experts here too. I am not one of them. I avoid using most of Googles reporting tools though not completely. Sorry. For the record, it is often quiet here on the weekends and most active in the mornings. That is because we are mostly pros and pay attention during work hours with some exception. You should hear something soon enough! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Full Referrer means URL which user came from. It could be familiar with your expectations only with filtering by another Dimension ("previous page path" = (entrance)).

But there is better report...

You need to look at Behaviour > Site Content > Landing Pages ("entrance pages") and then add secondary dimension Full Referrer.

Comment: Can you specify how to filter by Previous page path?  When I select this option, I just get a single line in the results and no referral information.  When I try the better report, I get the same results as the first report I created in my question above.

Comment: this does not change anything when the issue already applies to landing pages